# Django 1.10 Create Model Tables Automatically

Tags: database, sqlite, python-3.x, django-models

I am wondering if there is any way to create a new model table in SQLite with Django 1.10 (like writing general python code) without having to specify in the models.py. The situation is if there is a new member registered on my website, then I will create a new model table for them to hold their data. Specifically:

step 1: John Doe registered on my site

step 2: The system create a model table named db_johnDoe (with same set of fields as of the others)

step 3: The system can insert and edit data of the db_johnDoe according to John's behavior on the website.

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to create a table for each user. This may cause bad performance and low security. Why don't you create a table named `userInfo` and put `user`.`userID` as a foreign key?

Comment: The reasons for wanting to create tables for different users is:

1. Not wanting to make single table too big as the user's data accumulate with time. I expect one user table will contain ten of thousands of data as time goes by. Big single table also causes bad performance;

2. Also, separating different users' data makes further database management easier, like editing and removing records from the database; and

3. Just wanting to know, for the sake of more knowledge in my Django learning.

Comment: There're many other approaches to satisfy your requirements. Anw, you can create a table by calling a raw query and off course, you have to read your data by raw query too

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Answer (score -1):

Thank you both, especially @Hary TD's reference which was very helpful. Based on that, I figured out how to do that and summarized as below for others' reference:

```
from django.db import connection
db_name = 'ADDRESSES'    

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE %s (
     USERNAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     ADDRESS VARCHAR(64),
     CITY VARCHAR(64), 
     ZIPCODE VARCHAR(16), 
     UNIQUE (ADDRESS, CITY, ZIPCODE))""" % db_name)
```

Other sql commands can also be executed in this way.